# dnode PHP Fatal error: Class 'DNode\DNode' not found

Tags: php, node.js, npm

I've recently installed node.js with and npm on my linux server I have the npm server script running ok but when I try to execute the PHP client app I get the following error PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DNode\DNode' not found. I've google the heck out of it but haven't found much about it. can somebody help me set up npm for the first time?

Comment: There is no "PHP client app".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP interpreter is looking for a class `DNode` and cannot find it. You need to tell it where to find that class. How to best do that is not something we could tell you without knowing your setup.

Comment: I've found the way to do it is by using composer but I can't figure out how to specify a vendor name I'm trying to use {
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*" but it still doesn't work
    }

Comment: If you mean "dnode/dnode" - there is no version 1.0.* of that package yet. Hint: you can look up dnode on Packagist to find a list of all available releases -> https://packagist.org/packages/dnode/dnode

Comment: I really messed things up I accidently tried to install dnode/dnode:1.0.0 and then you showed me the correct version only when I try to install it I get this error message - Installation request for dnode/dnode 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by dnode/dnode[1.0.0]. and it doesn't let me install 0.1.3 how can I fix it?

Comment: I've tried to delete all cache files and composer files, rebooted, switched directories re downloaded and it still trying to use 1.0.0

Comment: but if I put dnode/dnode:1.0.0 back into the composer.json file then all the other modules install fine. I hope I don't have to reinstall linux. I'm going to try to install it correctly in a virtual machine

Comment: what most of the howto install node-js fail to tell you is that you have to check dnode out from git-hub  with a command similar to thisgit clone git://github.com/bergie/dnode-php.git
then cd into the dnode-php directory and get composer with wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar then finally install dnode with the command sudo php composer.phar install

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by me and the socket server is running